# Remove Chart.js Gridline Overlap

Tags: chart.js

I was wondering if anyone could help, ive done some extensive googling but i can't seem to find an answer,

I am using Chart.js graph to display some data, I'm trying to style the graph so it lines up with my DIVs below. however there seems to 3-4 px worth of gridline overlap on the vertical axis, would any one know how to remove this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set `drawTicks: false` to fix it. Those lines are meant to act as pointers to the ticks.

```
// Chart.js v3.9.1
options.scales.x.grid.drawTicks = false;
```

[Documentation for Grid Line Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration)

Answer (score -1):

you need to disabled it , try this

```
var options = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display: false,  
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
               display: false, 
            }   
        }]
    }
}
```